# O Stack Overflow é open source?

Tags: debate, stackoverflow

Já ouvi falar que é possível baixar a base de dados, mas e o código fonte?

Comment: Não, não é possível baixar o código fonte. Mas tem componentes que eles abriram, como o [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper).

Comment: É verdade que a base de dados pode ser baixada?

Comment: [Sim](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/224922/167534), mas parte dos dados (como votos) não está disponível, por questões éticas, de privacidade etc. Também tem uma ferramenta para [explorar](https://data.stackexchange.com) uma cópia do banco hospedada por eles mesmos. Isso além da API.

Comment: Tens alguns dados que podes obter, https://data.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Como disseram nos comentários, temos algumas maneiras de fornecer os dados dos sites (guardadas informações como dados pessoais ou votos). A primeira é usando o [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/), que permite rodar queries numa versão do banco de dados atualizada semanalmente. A outra são os [data dumps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/224922/) semestrais.

Mas o código fonte é fechado. Grande parte do motivo é que certas heurísticas da plataforma - regras para impedimento de perguntar/responder; requerimentos de algumas medalhas; filtros anti-spam ou contra manipulação de votos - não podem ser tornadas públicas sem comprometer sua eficácia. Isso colocaria a integridade do sistema em risco.

Não é tanto uma questão comercial (tanto que não nos importamos com clones), mas sim de proteção à plataforma e suas comunidades.